# How to get HTML code as String from a HTML file in java?

Tags: java, html, string

I need to get HTML code as String from an existing HTML file? How can I do that in Java?

I tried the following, but the result was something that is not html syntax.

```
        File htmlFile = new File(filePath);
        StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String str;
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(htmlFile));
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                contentBuilder.append(str);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        String htmlCodeAsString = contentBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: Read the file like any other text file.

Comment: Do you mean with selenium or just a regular file? some code?

Comment: “…the result was something that is not HTML syntax.”  Perhaps you should tell us what that result was, instead of making us guess?

Comment: Sorry, the code works fine. It was my mistake... I was constantly looking at the wrong file path...

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();
String str;

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename.html"));
while((str = in.readLine())!=null)
      bldr.append(str);

in.close();

String content = bldr.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a Scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.html"));
String text = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
scanner.close();
```

The regex **\A** marks the beginning of the input. Scanner uses a buffer which default size is 1024, but will be increased by the Scanner when needed.